# JPA on Google App Engine: When calling persist(...), does it always happen in a transaction?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, guice, datanucleus, guice-persist

In my application I am persisting an entity that has a number of unowned children.

It seems that the call to `persist` which does the persisting of the entity and all children happens inside a transaction because I get an error when I do not enable cross-group transactions (and the children live in different entity groups as the parent entity).

Is it possible to have the persisting being done non-transactional?

(In case this information is needed: I am using Guice to inject a request-scoped `Provider<EntityManager>` into my service object.)

ADDED:

Here is a simple test case:

```
@Entity public class Department {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Unowned
    Collection<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public Collection<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

}

@Entity public class Employee {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private Long id;        @ManyToOne  private Department department;      private String name;

    public Employee(String name) {      this.name = name;   }       public String getName() {       return name;    }

    public void setName(String name) {      this.name = name;   }    }
```

Now, when I do:

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
try {
    Department department = new Department();
    department.getEmployees().add(new Employee("Joe"));
    em.persist(department);
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

I get:

> ```
> Illegal argument
> ```
>
> Caused by:
>
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Illegal argument  at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:298)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:197)
>     at com.example.jpa.JpaServlet.doGet(JpaServlet.java:23)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cross-group transaction
>   need to be explicitly specified, see
>   TransactionOptions.Builder.withXGfound both Element {   type:
>   "Department"   id: 17 }  and Element {   type: "Employee"   id: 18 }
>
> at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:33)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:70)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:94)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$CumulativeAggregateFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:142)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$TxnAwareFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:218)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.put(WrappedDatastoreService.java:112)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.putEntitiesIntoDatastore(EntityUtils.java:766)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:314)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.flush(JDOStateManager.java:3778)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.validateObjectForWriting(SCOUtils.java:1518)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.AbstractFKStore.validateElementForWriting(AbstractFKStore.java:396)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.validateElementForWriting(FKListStore.java:1036)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.internalAdd(FKListStore.java:195)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.addAll(FKListStore.java:114)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.CollectionMapping.postInsert(CollectionMapping.java:134)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeRelations(StoreFieldManager.java:809)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:367)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.flush(JDOStateManager.java:3778)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternalWithOrdering(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3888)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3811)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flush(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3751)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4141)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.transactionPreCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:428)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:398)
>     at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:287)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1090)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:193)
>     ... 36 more
>
> Caused by:
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cross-group transaction need to be
>   explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXGfound both
>   Element {   type: "Department"   id: 17 }  and Element {   type:
>   "Employee"   id: 18 }
>
> at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:33)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:70)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:94)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$CumulativeAggregateFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:142)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper$TxnAwareFuture.get(FutureHelper.java:218)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.put(WrappedDatastoreService.java:112)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.putEntitiesIntoDatastore(EntityUtils.java:766)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:314)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.flush(JDOStateManager.java:3778)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.validateObjectForWriting(SCOUtils.java:1518)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.AbstractFKStore.validateElementForWriting(AbstractFKStore.java:396)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.validateElementForWriting(FKListStore.java:1036)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.internalAdd(FKListStore.java:195)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.addAll(FKListStore.java:114)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.CollectionMapping.postInsert(CollectionMapping.java:134)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeRelations(StoreFieldManager.java:809)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:367)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.flush(JDOStateManager.java:3778)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternalWithOrdering(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3888)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3811)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flush(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3751)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4141)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.transactionPreCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:428)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:398)
>     at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:287)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1090)
>     at
>   org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:193)
>     at com.example.jpa.JpaServlet.doGet(JpaServlet.java:23)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

That's why I have been thinking that `persist` happens inside a transaction although I haven't begun one explicitly.

Here are the relevant debug messages from DataNucleus:

> 08:38:17,587 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - =================
>   Persistence Configuration =============== 08:38:17,587 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - DataNucleus Persistence Factory - Vendor:
>   "DataNucleus"  Version: "3.1.3" 08:38:17,588 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - DataNucleus Persistence Factory
>   initialised for datastore URL="appengine" driver="" userName=""
>   08:38:17,588 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - JDK : 1.6.0_26 on Linux
>   08:38:17,588 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Persistence API : JPA
>   08:38:17,588 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Plugin Registry :
>   org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry 08:38:17,588 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Persistence-Unit : transactions-optional
>   08:38:17,588 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Standard Options :
>   pm-singlethreaded, retain-values, nontransactional-read,
>   nontransactional-write, serverTimeZone=UTC 08:38:17,589 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Persistence Options : detach-on-close
>   deletion-policy=JDO2 08:38:17,589 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] -
>   Transactions : type=RESOURCE_LOCAL mode=optimistic
>   isolation=read-committed 08:38:17,589 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence]
>   - Value Generation : txn-isolation=read-committed connection=New 08:38:17,589 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - ClassLoading : jdo
>   08:38:17,589 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Cache : Level1 (soft),
>   Level2 (soft, mode=UNSPECIFIED), QueryResults (soft), Collections/Maps
>   08:38:17,589 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] -
>   =========================================================== 08:38:17,657 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Object Manager
>   "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@e4eb585" opened for datastore
>   "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager@516f3619" with
>   txn="org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl@5c48cd13" 08:38:17,688 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Making object persistent :
>   "com.example.jpa.Department@55b7bf86" 08:38:17,736 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Object
>   "com.example.jpa.Department@55b7bf86" has been marked for persistence
>   but its actual persistence to the datastore will be delayed due to use
>   of optimistic transactions or "delayDatastoreOperationsUntilCommit"
>   08:38:17,741 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Making object
>   persistent : "com.example.jpa.Employee@95d0a50" 08:38:17,742 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Object "com.example.jpa.Employee@95d0a50"
>   has been marked for persistence but its actual persistence to the
>   datastore will be delayed due to use of optimistic transactions or
>   "delayDatastoreOperationsUntilCommit" 08:38:17,747 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Transaction] - Transaction created [DataNucleus
>   Transaction, ID=Xid=
>   08:38:17,748 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Transaction] - Transaction begun for
>   ObjectManager org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@e4eb585
>   (optimistic=true) 08:38:17,757 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Transaction] -
>   Running enlist operation on resource:
>   com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreXAResource@7d7082d8, error
>   code TMNOFLAGS and transaction: [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=
>   08:38:18,024 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Transaction] - Started datastore
>   transaction: 0 08:38:18,026 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Transaction] -
>   Transaction committing for ObjectManager
>   org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@e4eb585 08:38:18,027 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - ObjectManager.internalFlush() process
>   started using ordered flush - 2 dirty objects 08:38:18,105 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Managing Persistence of Class :
>   com.example.jpa.Employee [Table : com.example.jpa.Employee,
>   InheritanceStrategy : new-table] 08:38:18,136 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Managing Persistence of Class :
>   com.example.jpa.Department [Table : com.example.jpa.Department,
>   InheritanceStrategy : new-table] 08:38:18,316 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Field
>   "com.example.jpa.Department.employees" is being persisted for
>   "cascade-persist". 08:38:18,331 INFO  [DataNucleus.Persistence] -
>   Object "com.example.jpa.Department@55b7bf86" has a collection
>   "com.example.jpa.Department.employees" yet element
>   "com.example.jpa.Employee@95d0a50" doesnt have the owner set. Managing
>   the relation and setting the owner. 08:38:18,333 WARN 
>   [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Meta-data warning for
>   com.example.jpa.Employee.department: Error in meta-data for
>   com.example.jpa.Employee.department : The datastore does not support
>   joins and therefore cannot honor requests to place related objects in
>   the default fetch group.  The field will be fetched lazily on first
>   access.  You can modify this warning by setting the
>   datanucleus.appengine.ignorableMetaDataBehavior property in your
>   config.  A value of NONE will silence the warning.  A value of ERROR
>   will turn the warning into an exception. 08:38:18,354 DEBUG
>   [DataNucleus.Persistence] - ObjectManager.internalFlush() process
>   finished 08:38:18,355 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Transaction] - Illegal
>   argument org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusFatalUserException: Illegal
>   argument

Comment: why not present your code for how you're doing persist? and show the log at DEBUG level for one such persist

Comment: I will do after I have set up a test case reproducing my findings.

Comment: Hope the added code and stack trace helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just faced with the same issue and can confidently say that transaction committed when you call

```
EntityManager.close();
```

Here is some [prove](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.2.5/org/datanucleus/ExecutionContextImpl.java#383) from DataNucleus JPA implementation

Answer (score 2):

a bit late but I thought it would be useful for others. I have faced the same issue while using JPA with Google App Engine. But following code worked for me. Hope it helps-

```
try{
    EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
    try{
        t.begin();
        //Do stuff
        em.persist(persistObject);
        t.commit();
    }finally {
        if (t.isActive())
            t.rollback();
    }
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the that your transaction is cross group transaction for jpa. read below document specially cross group transaction for jpa/jdo

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions?csw=1

for my case adding below line in the persistance.xml resolved this issue.

```
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly from the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXGfound both Element { type: "Department" id: 17 } and Element { type: "Employee" id: 18 }

at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:33)
```

the datastore is running in a (low-level) transaction (shown in the log too), and it requires multi-entity-groups to be enabled to do what you want there.

Comment: This is what I thought, namely that a transaction is happening behind the scenes when I call persist. My question was actually whether persist always has to run atomically or whether there is a way to run persist non-transactionally. (I'm sorry in case my original question wasn't clear enough.)